# PySpark -- Convert List of Rows to Data Frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The problem I'm *actually* trying to solve is to take the first/last N rows of a PySpark dataframe and have the result be a dataframe. Specifically, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
 my_df.head(20).toPandas()
```

However, because `head()` returns a list of rows, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'toPandas'
```

So, I'm looking either for method that will return the first N rows of PySpark dataframe *as a dataframe*, or a method for converting these lists of rows into a dataframe. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `limit`:

```
>>> df = sc.parallelize((("a", 1), ("b", 2))).toDF()
>>> df.limit(1).toPandas()
  _1  _2
0  a   1
```

with `pd.DataFrame`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(df.head(1), columns=df.columns)
  _1  _2
0  a   1
```